# Username RegEx Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, nsregularexpression

**Username regex should be any string at least 8 characters long. In this string there can be @ sign, period, digits or not. I put some valid and invalid test cases below. How can I achieve this?**

Valid:

```
user@user.com 
adminuser1 
user.user@user.com
```

Invalid:

```
user@user.user.com
1adminuser1
```

Currently I have:

```
let usernameRegex = "\\A\\w{6,30}\\z"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to over-restrict the emails used in usernames. A basic email pattern is `\S+@\S+\.\S+` that matches something like an email, but it appears you do not want to allow the username to start with a digit and the domain part cannot contain 2 dots.

With those assumptions, there is a way to "fix" your pattern as

```
"^(?=\\S{8})[a-zA-Z]\\w*(?:\\.\\w+)*(?:@\\w+\\.\\w{2,4})?$"
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9IDvF7/1). Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\\S{8})` - the string should contain at least 8 non-whitepsace chars right after string start
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `\\w*` - 1+ word chars
- `(?:\\.\\w+)*` - 0+ sequences of `.` followed with 1+ word chars
- `(?:@\\w+\\.\\w{2,4})?`  - an optional sequence of:

  - `@` - a `@` symbol
  - `\\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `\\.` - a dot
  - `\\w{2,4}` - 2, 3 or 4 word chars
- `$` - end of string.

A very generic regex allowing many more chars than just letters/digits or underscores would be [`"^(?=\\S{8})(?!\\S*@\\S*\\.\\S*\\.)[a-zA-Z]\\S*(?:@\\S+\\.\\S+)?$"`](https://regex101.com/r/7unjnJ/1/). It  differs from the above in the usage of `\S` (any non-whitespace char) and just uses a negative lookahead `(?!\\S*@\\S*\\.\\S*\\.)` that fails the match if there are 2 dots anywhere after `@`.

Comment: Excellent answer !!

Comment: Thank you for linking the https://regex101.com/ site. It helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This expression validates the user names of the first letter type, then it may or may not have numbers, then it may or may not have a character of type '.' or '_' and then you can have letters or numbers

```
[a-z]+[0-9]*[_.-]?[a-z0-9]
```